# Running tests multi-process, multi-threaded on multiple machines with Pytest

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, pytest, distributed-computing

I'm using pytest to run a few thousands of tests against an API.
The need is now to not only use multiprocessing (pytest-xdist) and multithreading (pytest-parallel) but to also have them run on multiple machines (still keeping the multi process and threading capabilities).

This is the current state, the need is to basically duplicate this chart.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYCyh.jpg

Our last resort will be to develop a test runner service that will be deployed on as many machines as needed, and use an sqs so these machines can pull work from there.

Are there any better way of achieving this? Using pytest or maybe combined with Jenkins.

Comment: `pytest-xdist` can run the tests distributed on multiple machines. If you are looking for load testing libraries, there are specialized frameworks that do that well, like `locustio`, that can create high load from different machines simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks, What I saw was the xdist may give me this, but not multithreading.